# How to delete old photos from shared media in telegram group

Tags: telegram

I am an admin to a group in telegram and would like to delete some old photos from the shared media for all the members.
When I select the photos and choose delete, when I check with other members they still can see them.
Is there a way to delete old photos for everyone in a group? 
(It is not a supergroup)

Thanks
Bahara

Comment: Your question isn't about programming and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You can try posting this over at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Please contact Telegram Support